# Text imported from a software not the same as text written

Tags: excel

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPv3P.png)
[pasted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n3JM.png)

I have imported data from a data logger into excel through copying and pasting the data. The issue is that when I type the exact same text in another cell identical to the other excel says they are not the same.

I need to have this set up so that data can be pasted into the document and then a match and index function can pull data out from a time stamp, e.g. "12/09/2019 14:05:03"

at the moment the function returns an N/A value.

Thanks in advance CB

I set up an if function and then compared what I had typed into excel vs what I pasted in and it said they were dissimilar. However, after pressing enter after pressing the copied cell, the result changed and it said that they are the same.

This is the function I use, it works when I hit enter on the pasted raw data but not before;
=INDEX('4. Paste Raw Data'!CZ7:CZ10000,MATCH(Q3,'4. Paste Raw Data'!$DB$7:$DB$10000,0),105)

The cell with the 12.00 works for an unknown reason, it is just a match function on its own.

Comment: Is that timestamp really seen as time and date by Excel or is it seen as a string?

Comment: sorry, how does one check this? I checked the formatting and it is set to a time and date format, is that what you mean?

Comment: One way to check is to use `ISNUMBER(<cell>)` which should return `TRUE` if the content of the cell referred to is actually date and time.

Comment: Yes, they return a value of TRUE, so I am not sure where the problem lies. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact VLOOKUP formula you have?

Comment: the formula is in the post now; =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Q5,'4. Paste Raw Data'!$B$7:$DA$10000,103,FALSE),"")

Comment: "...it works when I hit enter on the pasted raw data but not before..." - What does that mean? Please clarify exactly all the steps of what you do. You may want to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have edited the post to make it a bit more clear